# Two inequations of curvature tensor.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

How to get the two inequations 1 and 2.

And I think the RHS of  1.4.2 should be 
$$
\Delta(\nabla R_m)+2R_m*(\nabla R_m)
$$

Besides, What's the define of $A*B$?

Soryy for my lazy, the below picture is from the 191th page of [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947)

=================================================================
[image]